# Node.JS binary data URL Decoding to UTF-8 issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, urldecode, utf8-decode

When i am sending binary data with `UTF-8` encoded from PHP client to Node.JS server, Node.JS internally encodes this data to URL Encode(percentage encoding). I guess Node.JS doesn't have support for UTF-8 as i already checked with base64 and it was working fine. I googled a lot and i found that everyone is facing the same issue. I manually checked the string but I get `"URIError: URI malformed"` error.

I also use the deprecated `functions unescape, escape, encodeURI and decodeURI`.

```
Little background of my work:
console.log(decodeURIComponent('%B1');
```

As you can search from the URLEncoding list that %B1 is for "±" sign. But i am getting the above mentioned error. This function can't decode other many special characters too. I don't know why Node.JS doesn't have support for the standard decoding style like UTF-8.

Please help me guys.

Comment: *"Node.JS internally encodes this data to URL Encode"* No. All encoding is done on the client in the scenario you describe.  *"I guess Node.JS doesn't have support for UTF-8"* - Wrong again. *"I also use the deprecated functions unescape, escape, encodeURI and decodeURI"* - Why would you do that? Bottom line is: Your question does not contain a problem statement (What are you trying to achieve?) and it does not contain enough meaningful code to be answerable. (What it does contain are  vague and unfounded assumptions.) Please improve your question.

Comment: It's plain impossible to send binary data as UTF-8 because UTF-8 is a **text** encoding. There are several encoders designed to do such task (such as UUEncode or base64). Whatever, do you really have **binary** data in the first place?

Comment: utf-8 encoded "±" is "%C2%B1" if you try that it does not throw...

Comment: Thanks Holger Will. But i am getting only "%B1" for "±".
From php Client side, I encode pdf, image or doc data by using utf8_encode function. Plus i use cURL to post request to server.
And if all the encoding is done on the client side then why i am getting percentage encoding data on node.js server side?

Comment: As I am getting the data in parameters, I log the data using req.body.content ('content' is the parameter contains the encoded data).
Here is the output:

Comment: As I am getting the data in parameters, I logged the data using req.body.content ('content' is the parameter contains the encoded data).
Output:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8SGP_B0ld44b2JKMTNxTm91M2s/view?usp=sharing

So my question is
1). Why i am getting URLEncoded Data in the first place while i sent the data using utf8_encode function in Php Client?
2). I certainly believe that my utf-8 data is encoded with URLEncoding. I try unescape, escape, encodeURI ,decodeURI and decodeURIComponent functions. But i am getting improper output.
And my que are not on the basis of any assumptions.